# Google Apps Calendar Resource API v1 (Atom/OAuth 1.0) likely lifespan?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I work with a Google Apps for Education domain and have been asked to write an application that maintains some Google Calendar resources and permissions thereof.

I am aware that Google has deprecated support for OAuth 1.0/1.0a and is moving away from Atom based services to JSON based services.

It therefore concerns me that the [Google Apps Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/) is currently old style Atom/OAuth 1.0.  I'm loathed to write an application using Atom/OAuth 1.0 if it is likely it will become obsolete within months.  I'm guessing the API is currently being rewritten in the JSON/OAuth 2.0 style?

If possible could somebody tell me the likely time-scale for the rewrite? (or alternative solutions I could consider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, in relation to the likely lifespan of the API (apologies for the legalese).  I have discovered that:

The Google Apps Calendar Resource API v1 is one of the [Google Apps Admin APIs subject to the Google's deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-api-list#deprecation_apis).  The [Google deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-api-terms) states that Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate this API without changes until 20th April 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable good faith judgment):

- required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a
  change in applicable law or relationship), or
- doing so could create a security risk or substantial economic or
  material technical burden.

After 20th April 2015, the Deprecation Policy will not apply.